# how to get only time from date in ISO formate

Tags: javascript, iso

How to extract only time from the date which is present in ISO format?
I tried this:

```
var d = new Date('1970-01-15T03:32:12.000Z'); //ISO-8601 formatted date returned from server
console.log(d.getTime());// 1222332000
```

Expected op is : `03:32:12`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since your server returns an ISO-8601 formatted date which has a predefined format, you can convert it to ISO string using `toISOString()` and then get the substring of the time value:

```js
var d = new Date('1970-01-15T03:32:12.000Z'); 
console.log(d.toISOString().substr(11,8));
```

Answer (score 0):

`Date.getTime()` returns the time in UNIX epoch format.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time

To access only the parameters you are interested in, you can use `Date.getMinutes()`, `Date.getMinutes()`, etc. See docs on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

*Note:* Do not forget to spend one thought on time zones when you work with `Date`
's time, especially when your app runs in different regions.

Answer (score 0):

You have to manually build the time string using `Date.prototype` methods: [getHours](https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencje/Obiekty/Date/getHours), [getMinutes](https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencje/Obiekty/Date/getMinutes) and [getSeconds](https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencje/Obiekty/Date/getSeconds)

Or use [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) library.

Answer (score 0):

`Date.getTime()` gives you the unix timestamp, which is the number of seconds since january 1st 1970;

> The getTime() method returns the numeric value corresponding to the time for the specified date according to universal time.

*from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime)*

You need to format the date yourself, either by concatenating the output of the `Date.getHours()`, `Date.getMinutes()` and `Date.getSeconds()` methods, or by using one of the predefined formatting functions, like `Date.toTimeString()`. Checkout the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) to pick your choice.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `getHours()`,`getMinutes()` and `getSecondes()`. Then you can use it with strings or objects.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
d.toTimeString().split(' ')[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) to parse whatever format you like.

If you think moment.js is too big, there's another library call [dayjs](https://github.com/iamkun/dayjs). The same fashion API but just 2KB. (<del>Unfortunately, you can't do UTC time with dayjs yet.</del>)

Update: Thanks kun for notifying the updates. You can now use UTC with dayjs plugin since v1.8.9.

```js
var d = new Date('1970-01-15T03:32:12.000Z');
console.log(moment(d).utc().format('HH:mm:ss'));
dayjs.extend(dayjs_plugin_utc)
console.log(dayjs(d).utc().format('HH:mm:ss'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dayjs/1.8.9/dayjs.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dayjs/1.8.9/plugin/utc.js"></script>
```